# Image icon is greyed out after upload failure

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

When posting a question through the Android application, whenever an upload fails to upload, e.g. due to image size being over 2 MB, the image icon is greyed out as shown below:

[image: 2mb-funky-greyness]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fixed in version 1.0.84.